# should we delete the observer when unregister it?

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

```
Observer *o = New Observer();
Subject *s = new Subject() ;
s->register(o);

//Is it a good practice to delete the observer in the unregister function?
//I feel it is not. As the Observer object might still be in use,  for example , 
//it might be registered to another Subject. 
s->unregister(o);  

//So it is safe to rely on the client code to delete the object or rely on the smart pointer things
delete o;
```

I want to confirm whether my above understanding is correct regarding who should delete the observer object.

Comment: Just think of situation where you have an observer observing two different subjects. Besides that, you are doing things within unregister function that you don't mention in function name, so your function shoudl be called unregisterAndDelete, but then again, you have a function that does two logically separate things (registration management and resource housekeeping), which is bad idea to begin with.

Comment: One other thought: you should most probably unregister when deleting object (except if the subject knows somehow that the registered observer is deleted). If you can satisfy nothrow guarantee in the unregister function, or observer's destructor, for that matter, you should probably call unregister within observer's destructor, but as a downside, you should keep within the observer list of all the subjects observer is registered to (so that you can iterate through the list of subjects and unregister your observer from each one of them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with your observation. It is not a good practice to delete the observer in the unregister function - for the simple fact that "one who creates the resource must be responsible for deleting the resource"

This will avoid

- Magic behavior as perceived by the creator.
- Code behavior will be well defined - one who creates must delete. Which will lay overall foundation of understanding of development for new developers to your system.

Similar topic are discussed under lengths in all books with different nomenclature.

Answer (score 4):

I would say use smart pointers as no need to remember to call the `delete` explictly.

Comment: To be precise, use a shared pointer. This way the observer will be deleted once it is not registered anywhere.

Comment: @Tamas: I agree, for once we truly have a shared ownership, and thus the use of a shared pointer seems adequate.

Comment: Shared pointer here is only valid if the *ownership* of the object is truly shared. Just because a object has a reference to another object does not imply shared ownership. Ownership means that it should control its lifetime. For all we know the Subject might be directly or indirectly owned by the Observer. My experience has told me that shared ownership is seldom necessary and something to avoid if possible. I do not say that a smart pointer is wrong, just that we need to know more of how the architecture is modeled before assuming anything about ownership.

Answer (score 2):

From a design point of view it should be superfluous (while not wrong) to unregister the subjects, if the observer is well implemented. Relying on external code for a behaviour to be robust if it can be enforced can always be considered as poor design.

Regarding the use of smart pointers, if you need the control on the destruction point for some reason (close files at a given point in time for example to avoid access problems in later code) then you should delete explicitly, otherwise it is far more comfortable to rely on smart pointers. That is why there are existing.

Answer (score 2):

As the `Subject` did not allocate the `Observer`, it should not attempt to deallocate it. This allows the client of `Subject` to manage the lifetime and allocation strategy of `Observer`s in any way it chooses (custom allocator, statically allocated, automatic variable). It doesn't force the client to use `new`.

Obviously it is still to clients responsibility not to allow the `Observer` to be destroyed before it is "unregistered".

E.g.

```
Observer o;
Subject s;

s.register(&o); // could take a reference

// ...

s.unregister(&o);

// No potential for forgotten deletes
```

Comment: +1 For me this is the best reason to leave Observer alone. As it is the responsibility of the client to register an observer, it is a clear symmetry that it is also it's responsibility to unregister it. Thank you for mentioning that a reference could (I would like to say should) be used.

Comment: As the Observer is created in the stack and it will be destroyed when it goes out of scope,won't the Subject end up notifying an null object?

Comment: @pierr: The `Subject` is also a local variable but it will go out of scope first _even if unregister didn't work_.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your design. I personally prefer that deleting the Observer will automatically disassociate it with the subject, i.e deregister itself in the destructor. That saves the need to bother to deregister, which would require you to have references to both the Subject and the Observer at the point of destruction.

Answer (score 0):

Smartpointer or client code  (do not transfer ownership if possible)
If client code has created the object let the same code to destroy it :)

Answer (score 0):

Another argument against deleting is what the Subject object *communicates*.

By deleting the object your Subject object has taken ownership of the object, as it controls its lifetime. As a raw pointer is passed into the object, and not an auto_ptr or an unique_ptr I would assume as a user of Subject that it does not take ownership of the object without looking at the code. So I would say that the *interface* of Subject does not communicate that it takes ownership of the object. So Subject should not delete it, because someone else (probably) has ownership of it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid side effects like deleting the pointer to an object in a container, unless the container is responsible for creating the pointer as well.

The problems of pointers with the Observer pattern runs a bit deeper than this as well.

An Observer inherently has a reference of some kind to the Subject.  If that reference is a direct reference (e.g. not a handle), then if that object goes out of scope or gets deleted, when the Observer makes a Notify(...) call, it will throw an exception (or worse).  So you must ensure you Detach(...) from the observer when you delete the Subject.

Forgetting to do this is a problem, so I like the idea of building it into the base class of the virtual destructor.  This also means that the Subject has knowledge of the Observer (a reference to it) so it can call Detach(...).  Which puts you into a similar situation with the Observer (i.e. if it gets deleted).  The approach I have found simplest to use is to have the Observer actually be a singleton with Subjects registering for particular notifications, not just "I have some state for you to update".  This is consistent with the GoF Page 298, item 7, "Specifying modifications of interest explicitly".  Also, just plain makes sense to narrow the field on updates a bit.  It also allows hooking up any Subject form anywhere easier.

Another case to consider is when the Subject is deleted during your Notify(..) iteration.  In your Observer, you have a list of Subjects, A, B, and C.  You change state and call Notify(...) on A.  A deletes B.  Now you move on to call Notify(...) on B, which does not exist.  If you had it Detach(...) in the destructor, B may not be on the list any more.  But it might still if you chose to iterate over a copy of the Subjects you started with instead of the actual list (been there, done that).  Your Observer needs to handle a Detach(...) call during iteration for a Notify(...) for this reason.

I have a worked out example of this posted on a blog [here](http://www.nliapps.com/tools-you-build-part-i-observer/).